# Display of special characters \u{n}

Tags: swift, macos

Impossible to find the solution ; it does not work...
I've been on this for hours... A little help will give me the opportunity to sleep without a nightmare...
Where is the error ?

```
    let num: Int = 128150                       // smiley = "\u{1F496}"  =>  128150
    var str: String = String(num, radix: 16)
    str = str.uppercased()
    var wkHex: String = "\\u{"+str+"}"          // wkHex = "\u{"+str+"}"  not match
    wkHex.characters.removeFirst(0)             // remove "\" unnecessary at startIndex
    let cnt = wkHex.characters.count
    let zzz: Array = Array(wkHex.characters)
    var car: String = ""
    for i in 0...cnt - 1 {
        car.append(zzz[i])
    }
    outputChar.stringValue = car                // outputChar  is a Label (NSTextField)

    // output : \u{1F496} !    instead of :
```

Comment: Why don't you just use the emoji? I wouldn't expect a user to know the Unicode codes of the emojis they're using^^

Comment: "I've been on this for hours...". You could have spent some hours _learning_, plus five minutes writing the code like matt did.

Answer (score 1):

So the idea is to go from a code point to a character?

```
    let iii = 128150
    let char = Character(UnicodeScalar(iii)!)
    print(char) //
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift only allows you to use the `\u{...}` syntax at compile time. This means that the string won't be turned into the emoji at runtime, when the value of `num` is known.

To do this, you can use `UnicodeScalar`:

```
let unicode = UnicodeScalar(128150)
unicode?.description //
```